# Bash: If file exists, read line, do this *then* than, then continue to next line

Tags: bash, awk

Straight to the point: I need to do the following (psuedo-code):

```
if [ -f <file_that_exists> ]

then

while read
do


awk '{print "do stuff for " $1}' THEN immediately below it awk '{print "do stuff for" $2}'
Then continue to next line
```

The file I'm trying to parse has two columns (host pairs if you will):

```
host_1     host_2
host_3     host_4
```

What I need the output to look like is the following:

```
Do stuff for host_1
Do stuff for host_2
Do stuff for host_3
Do stuff for host_4
```

What I'm trying now looks like:

```
Do stuff for host_1
Do stuff for host_3
Do stuff for host_5
Do stuff for host_7
then
Do stuff for host_2
Do stuff for host_4
Do stuff for host_6
Do stuff for host_8
```

I'm not sure if I'm being very clear, so if you need further clarification please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: cant you just write a bash for loop ```for F in $(cat file); do echo "Do stuff for $F"; done```

Comment: Unfortunately not - chaining awk together will do the trick though, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're aiming for can be done in a single `awk` statement:

```
awk '{ print "Do stuff for " $1; print "Do stuff for " $2 }' filename
```

Or alternatively:

```
awk '{ printf "Do stuff for %s\nDo stuff for %s\n", $1, $2 }' filename
```

No need to use the shell to read from the file; just pass the file name to `awk` directly. The key to the above solution is that `awk` will read from the file, record by record (here: line by line), and have each field (here: host_1, host_2, etc.) in that line be encoded as $1 and $2. If you had a variable number of fields in each line, the solution would be a bit different (possibly involving a loop within `awk`) but the above is the simple case.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where you want to use a for-loop to iterate over the *words* in your file:

```
for host in $(< filename); then
    Do something with $host
done
```

or, read 2 words from each line

```
while read host_a host_b; do
    Do something with $host_a
    Do something with $host_b
done < filename
```